# Create some hash type structure in Gson to access values in json instead of creating custom classes

Tags: java, json, gson, android

If I have a json object inside a bigger json:

```
customer_data: {    
     details: {    
           personal_info: {    
                first: “George”  
                last: “Washington”                 
           }   
           order_details: {  
                 canceled: “true”   
                 id:”1234”  
       }  
}
```

If I want only specific values of `customer_data` besides traversing the structure using `getAsJsonObject` etc is there any other way to access them if I would like to avoid creating a `CustomerData` class since I won’t need to access all the data of `customer_data`?

**Note:** I am using Gson

Answer (score 0):

Gson don't supports data access via XPath anology, and if you don't want to use Data Binding, you have only two ways: Tree Model or Streaming API.
The simpliest will be Tree Model:

`JsonObject customerData = someBiggerJson.get("customer_data").getAsJsonObject();
String someInfo = customerData.get("some_field").gatAsString();
...`

In case of using Streaming API you should iterate in your json to field you need by your hands.

`reader = new JsonReader((<input_stream>)
reader.nextString()
reader.beginObject()
reader.endObject() etc..`